# Imagen con link no funciona HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, img

A la hora de hacer una imagen con link, según he visto en varias webs me dicen de hacer un  con un  dentro, pero a la hora de la verdad no funciona (osea, cuando abro la página en sí.)

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">
<link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css" />
</head>

<body>

  <div class="cuadrado" href="#KnowUs">

    <p id="cuadrado"></p>

    <p class="animate__animated animate__fadeInLeft" id="ContactUs">Contact Us</p>
    <a class="animate__animated animate__fadeInLeft" id="Know" href="#KnowUs" style="position: absolute; top:80px; text-decoration: none;">Know Us</a>



    <a id="CuadroCabecera1" class="animate__animated animate__fadeInLeft" style="font: montserrat; font-family: montserrat; font font-size: 0px; position: absolute; top: -100px; z-index: 3; text-decoration: none;" name="CyberSpace" href="2021 NERD EDITION.html">CyberSpace</a>


  </div>



  <div class="presentation">


    <p id="box2" style="font: montserrat; font-family: montserrat;"></p>
    <p class="Opacity"></p>
    <video src="video/falcon-heavy-starman.mp4" width="1920" height="1080" autoplay loop muted id="video"></video>
    <p id="intro" style="font: montserrat; font-family: montserrat;" class="animate__animated animate__fadeInLeft">Bienvenido a la red de satélites biplanetarios más seguros</p>
    <p id="descintro" style="font: montserrat; font-family: montserrat;"></p>
    <p id="text1" class="animate__animated animate__fadeInLeft" style="font: montserrat; font-family: montserrat; animation-duration: 6s;"> Ganadora de Mejor Empresa de Seguridad Online 2021TM.</p>
    <img src="img/satisfaction-guarantee-2109235_1280.png" alt="blank" class="Satiss">

  </div>




  <div class="Contactanos">

    <p id="Contact-Box" style="z-index: 1;"></p>
    <p id="List-2" style="z-index: 2;">Número: xxx-xxx-xxx</p>
    <p id="List-1" style="z-index: 3;">Correo Electrónico: cyberspaceassociates@gmail.com</p>
    <p id="List-3" style="z-index: 4;">Residencia: Montgomery, Alabama</p>


  </div>


  <div class="Know-us" name="KnowUs">

    <img src="img/clickhere.png" alt="blank" class="clickhere" href="https//:www.google.es">
    <p id="KnowUsTxt">Know Us</p>
    <p id="filter-mars"></p>
    ***
    <a href="https://www.google.com"><img src="img/mars.jpg" alt="Qries" class="mars"></a>***




  </div>
```

Vale, para orientaros, la línea de texto dónde yo quiero intruducir la imagen, se encuentra al final, en el ultimo div, es esta:

```
<a href="https://www.google.com"><img src="img/mars.jpg" alt="Qries" class="mars"></a>
```

Y es eso, he buscado la solucion durante horas y no he encontrado nada que me pueda ayudar, agradecería mucho vuestra colaboración. Un saludo!

Comment: yo copie y pegue tu linea, le puse una imagen de internet, y funciona perfectamente. El problema debe ser otro.

Comment: De que problema podríamos estar hablando Agustin?

Comment: vos a la imagen la podes ver correctamente? Y cuando haces click sobre ella que pasa? (Si no estás viendo la imagen, es que la estás referenciando mal)

Comment: La imagen claro que la veo, lo que ocurre, es que el link que yo quiero poner para poder clickar en la imagen no hace su funcion

Answer (score 0):

Prueba usando esta forma:

```html
<a href="https://www.google.com/">
    <img alt="Google" src="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-q8PytfYcbg8/Ty7eOLtALtI/AAAAAAAAFI8/ykMOUcs_f48/s200/Chrome+logo.png">
</a>
```